# Any way to optimize this NumPy indexed reassignation?

Tags: python, numpy

What I'm trying to achieve is basically HDR: grab the most intense pixel out of each exposure level and replace the corresponding pixel in the main image (or keep as-is if it's already the most intense).

I'm mainly looking to improve the `for` loop, as it's the main bottleneck when processing large arrays.

```py
hdr_data = np.array([main_scan.data, lower_scan.data, higher_scan.data])

maximum_intensities = hdr_data.max(axis=-1)
frame_indices = np.argmax(maximum_intensities, axis=0)

for i, index in enumerate(frame_indices):
    main_scan.data[i] = hdr_data[index, i, :]
```

`main_scan`, `lower_scan` and `higher_scan` are in `X*Y` shapes, and `hdr_data` is in `3*X*Y` shape

Comment: Can you make this example reproducible?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hdr_data   # (3,x,y) shape
maximum_intensities    # (3,x) shape
frame_indices # (x,) shape, values 0,1,2
```

iterative:

```
for i, index in enumerate(frame_indices):
    main_scan.data[i] = hdr_data[index, i, :]
```

try:

```
max_data = hdr_data[np.arange(x)[:,None], frame_indices] # (x,y)
```

`np.take_along_axis` can also do this; see its docs

test

```
In [340]: arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,10,4))

In [341]: idx=np.argmax(arr.max(axis=-1), axis=0)

In [342]: idx
Out[342]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)

In [343]: arr[np.arange(10),idx,:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[343], line 1
----> 1 arr[np.arange(10),idx,:]

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

oops, reverse the index order:

```
In [344]: arr[idx,np.arange(10),:]
Out[344]: 
array([[4, 2, 4, 9],
       [1, 9, 1, 4],
       [7, 0, 1, 4],
       [1, 6, 8, 9],
       [5, 9, 5, 1],
       [8, 5, 0, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 5],
       [7, 9, 8, 2],
       [2, 6, 4, 9],
       [7, 4, 1, 9]])
```

Comment: This works and looks like what I wanted, but performance is slightly worse than the for loop (~0.15 seconds difference with a 10 run timeit setup)

Comment: relative performance may vary with problem size.

Comment: This was with `uint16` arrays of shape `30 000 * 4 000`. I'll do some more benchmarks with differing data sizes to have a better idea

Comment: With large arrays, memory management is more complex, and can slow down whole-array methods.